# Как вывести часть текста из страницы WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, cms

Привет.

Есть код, он выводит текст до тега **more** с указанной мною страницы на главную страницу.

```
<?php
    global $paged;
    if(is_home() && $paged == "") :

        $my_query = new WP_Query('pagename=страница'); // тут надо указать название требуемой страницы
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

                the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) );

        endwhile; endif;
```

**Вопрос:**

как переписать код, чтобы он выводил часть текста после тега **more** с якоря **id**. То есть отрезок, у которого якорь **id** c **name**. Таких привязок на странице всего 2 после тега **more**, их нужно вывести в отдельные блоки **div**.

Выглядит так:

```
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>текст</p>
<--more-->
<div id="1"><a name="1"></a></div>
<h2>Заголовок 1</h2>
<p>текст</p>
<div id="2"><a name="2"></a></div>
<h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
<p>текст</p>
```

На главную страницу надо вывести в один блок текст с **id="1"**, а в другой блок **div** текст из **id="2"**.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь перед запросом:

```
global $more;
$more = 0;
```

Ну а дальше регуляркой вынуть текст:

```
preg_match_all("##", $my_query->the_post(), $result);

$array_blocks = array();

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($result[0]); $i++) {
                 // номер блока     // содержимое блока
    $array_blocks[$result[1][$i]] = $result[2][$i];
}
```

Comment: lampa 

Не получилось, блок пустой.

Comment: @Viher, сорри, про регулярку забыл, надо так:

    preg_match_all('#<div id="([0-9]+)"><a name="[0-9]+">(.*?)</a></div>#', $my_query->the_post(), $result);

Comment: Появился текст до тега more. 
<div id="([a-Z]+)"><a name="[a-Z]+">(.*?)</a></div>

Comment: lampa Почему запрос выводит текст до тега more?

    if (is_home()) :
        $my_query = new WP_Query('pagename='); 
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  
global $more;
$more = 0;
 
                the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) );   
  
preg_match_all('#<div id="([a-z]+)"><a name="[a-z]+">(.*?)</a></div>#', $my_query->the_post(), $result);
  
$array_blocks = array();

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($result[0]); $i++) {
               
    $array_blocks[$result[1][$i]] = $result[2][$i];
}
     endwhile; endif;